# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely

Tags: docker, jmeter, dockerfile

I want to launch Chrome browser using Docker but on running docker I am getting error "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely."

Error 2023-06-26 16:01:01,033 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Signing Room 1-1
2023-06-26 16:01:01,212 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.8.3', revision: 'e5e76298c3'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '1.8.0_362'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:234) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.8.3.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.getThreadService(ChromeDriverConfig.java:47) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:26) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:14) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:221) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:152) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:784) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:993) [jorphan.jar:5.4]
at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:976) [jorphan.jar:5.4]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:752) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:740) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:252) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_362]
2023-06-26 16:01:01,243 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: /app/apache-jmeter-5.4/bin/./Scripts//..//Data//AppUrl.csv Alias: /app/apache-jmeter-5.4/bin/./Scripts//..//Data//AppUrl.csv@827248723
2023-06-26 16:01:01,298 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!

DockerFile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/ubuntu:20.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=America/New_York



RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y apt-utils \
    build-essential \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    zip \
    && apt-get clean
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix


# CHROME INSTALLATION 




# RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install wget unzip zip -y


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2

# Set up the Chrome PPA
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list


# Update the package list and install chrome
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
RUN echo "complete"


# Set up Chromedriver Environment variables
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION 2.19
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_DIR /chromedriver
RUN mkdir $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Download and install Chromedriver
RUN wget -q --continue -P $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
RUN unzip $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR/chromedriver* -d $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Put Chromedriver into the PATH
ENV PATH $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR:$PATH


# CHROME INSTALLATION END

WORKDIR /app
COPY apache-jmeter-5.4 ./apache-jmeter-5.4

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/entrypoint.sh"]
RUN ["chmod", "a+x", "./apache-jmeter-5.4/bin/jmeter.sh"]  
RUN dos2unix /entrypoint.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you seen [ChromeDriver documentation](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection) which states

   > ChromeDriver uses **the same version number scheme as Chrome**. See https://www.chromium.org/developers/version-numbers for more details.

   so you need to download the chromedriver version which is exactly the same as your Chrome version and not use hard-coded value of `2.19` which is for Chrome like 5 years old
2. As per [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider migrating to [JMeter 5.6](https://lists.apache.org/thread/yw1zgbnc106frjc9lc4pgnbgo5mjss41). Moreover JMeter 5.4 is suffering from [Log4Shell](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4Shell) so your container won't pass security audits.